# member function as template parameter and c++17 equivalent

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, auto, member-functions

In clang 4.0, taking advantage of c++17 auto template parameter, I can now write functions like this (which turns out to be very useful in many situations):

```
template<auto member_function, typename OBJECT>
auto call_member_fct(OBJECT object){
    return (object.*member_function)()
}
```

(G++ >= 7 offers the same possibility but I have not tested it)

The function has the useful feature that you can call it with a single template parameter, the actual member function:

```
call_member_fct<&action::count>(action())
```

Unfortunately vs2017 does not permit this.
Is there a syntax workaround that would permit to use the same call with ***single*** template parameter in vs2017, with the function signature and object automatically deducted?

Comment: You missed the C++ tag which is pretty relevant and important to your post. Hopefully it'll get some attention now.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly 100% the same, but should do for most situations. You can have the member function a parameter:

```
template <class T, class Ret>
auto yolo(auto (T::* mem) () -> Ret, T& obj)
{
    return (obj.*mem)();
}
```

Call like this:

```
struct X { auto foo() { return 24; }};

auto test()
{
    X x;
    return yolo(&X::foo, x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually I want the member function as a template argument so this answer does not work for my use-case. Having the member function available at compile-time makes the generated code in my case (message dispatching) smaller and faster.